# What to consider when making a custom progress bar in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, progress-bar

I have a question about progress bars in the android studio. I have been searching the web but can't seem to find enough information on custom progress bars. I would like to make a progress bar that fills a cup with liquid and I need guidance on how to do just that. is there a way to change the progress bar attribute within the android studio to do that or would I have to make an animation and link it using levels so that it acts as a progress bar?

I am not looking for the code to solve my problem I simply need some guidelines.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well In my opinion it would be better if you do it via the animation approach because it gives you more control compared to the normal progressbar

Comment: I agree but I simply lack information on how should continue with this .. in which format does the animation need to be? how long does it need to be? should I use vector animations? how to call the progress bar in activity etc.

Comment: Well again opinion-based answer here If I were you I would be creating Lottie animation and from Lottie library, I would try to set frame programmatically. I am not sure whether it's achievable via Lottie but that were I would start

Comment: hmm will give that a try thank you

Comment: Take a look at this [blog post on icon animation techniques](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html) by A.J. Lockwood, especially the section on clippping paths